# Ubuntu make symbolic link between new folder in Home to existing folder

Tags: ubuntu, symbolic-link

To the point. I have Ubuntu Maverick running on my Lenovo G450. Before, it was Windows 7. All my data are inside another partition, its NTFS.

FSTAB line to mount that partition :

**/dev/sda5   /data  ntfs  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137    0  0**

Inside /data there are folder Musics, Graphics, Tools, Cores, etc.

If I'm about to create new folder, let see, GFX on */home/apronouva/GFX* and make it link or pointing to */data/Graphics*, how do I do that ?

So when I open */home/apronouva/GFX* the content will be the same as inside */data/Graphics* .. and whatever changes I made inside GFX, it will also affect */data/Graphics*

I tried : 
**$** ln -s /data/Graphics /home/apronouva/GFX

it resulted : error, cannot make symbolic link between folder

Thanks in advance,

Fath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the -d option in your ln command , according to the manual that is what is used to link directories.

Also if you have a GUI (GNOME) you can always right click on the directory you want to link to and click the make link option that appears in the right click menu.

i.e.

1. Right click on /data/Graphics
2. Then choose make link
3. Drag the new link where ever you
   need and rename it.

Comment: the GUI tricks, works like charm :) thanks. Never really put attention to that, I guess the obvious one is sometimes can't be seen easily. Again, thanks :)

Comment: Cool no prob at all